# Why slf4j Logger has no log method?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I am wondering why there is no

```
logger.log(level, ...)
```

in slf4j. Is there a precise reason? When migrating from log4j to slf4j and using logback, this is causing me headache !

Answer (score 2):

slj4j is just a Wrapper around the actual [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) implementation, in order to provide flexibility to change the underlying implementation.

Having said that , instead *.log(,)* notation, slf4j uses *logger.level()* like - logger.**debug()** logger.**info()** etc

and that too based on the supported LEVEL defined in your underlying logger configuration for example logger.properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but I think `log(Level...` type method is not in the interface for some combination of these reasons:

- Keep number of methods in interface down
- Avoid needing to define numeric log levels in the interface
- Without numeric levels, just enum values, advantage of such method is not clear
- Being as independent as possible from underlying log system's log levels by not having log level class at all
- When dynamic log level would be desired by application, alternative might be [Marker concept](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Marker.html).